# Random access violation with brcc32

Tags: compiler-errors, c++builder, finalbuilder

We are getting random access violation (couple of months now) on random project. We have a build job script run by FinalBuilder. But if any of the project is manually build either in Embarcadero IDE or FinalBuilder, no issues. At this point I do not know how to move forward. What should I look for to check for issues?

There is nothing new that was changed on the resources.

```
Generating Resource File
Including ICON File :B:\\Build\\Glyph\\ApexIcons\\32\\Apex_32.ico
Including Manifest File :B:\Cai\Apex-Utility\Data\Default\SpecialData\EmbarcaderoManifest.xml

Compiling resource file : Tkhedit.rc
Microsoft (R) Windows (R) Resource Compiler Version 6.0.5724.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

Creating Tkhedit.RES
Using codepage 1252 as default

Tkhedit.rc.
Writing ICON:1, lang:0x409, size 4264
Writing GROUP_ICON:MAINICON,    lang:0x409, size 20.
Writing 24:1,   lang:0x409, size 712.
Writing VERSION:1,  lang:0x409, size 928
Resource Compiler OK.

Running MSBuild with parameters : /property:Config="Debug";BDSINCLUDE="C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\include";BDSLIB="C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\lib";SkipResGeneration=true;Platform=Win32 /nologo /target:"Build"  "B:\Cai\Cpp\Program\Tk\Tkhedit\Tkhedit.cbproj" /logger:FinalBuilderLogger,"C:\Program Files (x86)\FinalBuilder 8\FinalBuilder.MSBuild.Logging.v3.5.dll" /noconlog /v:normal
Build started 4/29/2019 8:25:03 PM.
Project "B:\Cai\Cpp\Program\Tk\Tkhedit\Tkhedit.cbproj" on node 0 (Build target(s)).
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(2630,5): error MSB6006: "brcc32" exited with code -1073741819.
Done Building Project "B:\Cai\Cpp\Program\Tk\Tkhedit\Tkhedit.cbproj" (Build target(s)) -- FAILED.

Build FAILED.
"B:\Cai\Cpp\Program\Tk\Tkhedit\Tkhedit.cbproj" (Build target) (1) ->
(_RcCoreCompile target) ->
C:\Program Files (x86)\Embarcadero\Studio\18.0\Bin\CodeGear.Cpp.Targets(2630,5): error MSB6006: "brcc32" exited with code -1073741819.
0 Warning(s)
1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:01:16.93
MSBuild returned non zero : 1
```

Embarcadero Berlin 10.2
FinalBuilder 8

Comment: What you are experiencing is not an access violation, and it is not occurring in the C++ compiler at all, it is happening in the [resource compiler](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/BRCC32.EXE,_the_Resource_Compiler) instead. I would suggest double-checking your resources to make sure they are not corrupted. You might need to compile the resources separately into a pre-compiled `.res` file, and then just link that file into your main project.

Comment: While it is true that it is not occurring in the C++ compiler instead resource compiler (brcc32 instead of bcc32), the error is an access violation (-1073741819). Linking .res separately is an option, but not workable since we have different languages and they are built on a integration machine. But thanks for weighing in your thoughts.